# Unable to Store Data into a String Array while trying to load the data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, arrays, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know the question looks confusing but let me tell you what I've got.
I am trying to get the data from a Realtime Database and trying to store it in a array, this is my function

```
void fuctocreatesubname(){

    for(int i=0;i<numberofsubjects;i++){
        final int i1 = i;
        DatabaseReference namedbref = databaseTracks.child(ArrayToStoreSubpath[i]);
        namedbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayToStoreSubName[i1] = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.v("ArraytoSubpathname",ArrayToStoreSubName[i1]);
                int j = 0;
                while(j==i1){
                    functotransferarray(ArrayToStoreSubName[j],j);
                    j++;
                }
                return;
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            return;
            }
        });

        Log.v("Out","I AM OUT");
    }
}
```

In this function : `String [] ArrayToStoreSubName = new String[8];` is a global variable and in Logs it shows that the Array has stored the value. But when I try to access this array in any other function the value automatically becomes Null.

Is there any way to solve this? Also, this method that I am using seems complicated is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: why you are defined fixed size of array. use ArrayList<String> instead

Comment: @DivyeshPatel l did and it worked. I was also trying to use a loop , I guess that was stupid. Now I am using for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) and it works great